# Работа с модулем Datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

скажите пожалуйста есть ли возможность вытянуть количество недель из типа datetime.date
например у меня есть такое время`a = datetime.date(1,12,19)`
Можно ли сделать это с типом данныхa = datetime.timedelta например
`stop = datetime.date(2019,9,27) - datetime.date(2019,9,17)`

Answer (score 0):

В Python в `datetime` модуле есть метод `timedelta` ([официальная документация](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)), который позволяет оперировать следующими "разницами"

```
class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0
```